# iPhone storage totals fail to account for missing 7.5GB - what's using this space?

Tags: iphone, storage

I have a 128GB iPhone. When I go to Settings > Storage > Storage (section) > Manage Storage, it tells me 106.69GB is used and 15.05GB is free. That totals 121.74GB. (Yes, I understand the total will be less than 128GB because [an Apple gigabyte is 1000 x 1000 x 1000](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/111721/iphone-storage-too-far-from-its-actual-total-amount) and not 1024 x 1024 x 1024. So be it.)

However when I go through all of the applications that are listed, and add them up, I get 97.10GB.

So at the top it tells me 106.69GB is used, but tallying the listed items totals 97.10GB. That leaves a difference of 9.59GB which is apparently used up, but not in the list.

As I understand it, iOS should be about 2GB - which means there should still be 7.5GB that isn't accounted for anywhere. Given the phone reports I have about 15GB free, adding an additional 7.5GB would actually increase my free space by 50%, and that's worth hunting down.

What gives?

Comment: Did you include the System and Other System Data in your count?Those are the last 2 items in my iPhone storage count and they take up 10.86 GB. I noticed in your description you estimated the size of iOS pretty badly, so maybe that doesn't display for you? If you don't have those 2 items at the bottom you may have an older version of iOS that doesn't display them.

Comment: It doesn't list "System" or "Other System Data". Is iOS really 9.5GB? Articles online suggest 1.5 to 2GB and if an update downloads itself onto my phone, it's usually about 2GB. Under Settings > About, it tells me version is 10.1.1 (14B100).